# What can one do with Microsoft's Paint 3D?

Tags: paint-3d, paint

Paint 3D seems to be a very user-friendly software; one that can easily manipulate 3D shapes and objects. I was trying to find online what cool and useful things I can do with it but I couldn't find much.

I am not from a graphic design background. Just a random guy who once opened Paint 3D. I sit and play with it for long hours never knowing what to actually do with it.

Is there a resource that helps me to untap the potential of Paint 3D or do people just use high-end softwares like Blender, Adobe etc?

Comment: User friendliness in the first few minutes isnt terribly useful for a future you if it turns out to be limiting your ability to do stuff. Anyway all even remotely advanced software have infinite usecases. Try writing a list for all uses for a hammer.

Comment: You can for ex. become famous with it. Paint a realistic looking replica of this scene https://blogs.icrc.org/cross-files/wp-content/uploads/sites/106/2018/03/1857858274_2848d4b77a_b-1024x620.jpg except replace the sitting persons with a their modern days colleagues. Let one of them stand, (the rest can sit like in the original). Let there be a speech balloon which says: Vladimir Putin, guilty, death by hanging! There exists at least one country where you can become sensitive to catch some lead or fall down over a roof edge.  If you live there avoid lead and slippery roofs after drawing.

Comment: In most instances the largest hurdle for software is how does it interact with *other* software. What formats can you save work as? The best app in the world can mean very little if it keeps everything in a proprietary format at all times.

Comment: I'd suggest you have [a look on youtube at some tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=paint+3D+tutorial). That's probably the best way to evaluate its capabilities. Should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

This is, of course, opinion-based.

I think of it as an elementary-level 3D drawing software. The same as if you use Play-doh.

You could make a diorama of the solar system with Play-doh with basic shapes, and you also could make a diorama on Paint3D. You can even add texture to the planets.

I am sure that a cover or diagram for a science project is useful.

The main problem with a very user-friendly software is that normally that means "limited options" and that translates into limited "editability" or control.

But when you want to improve your work the next day, you are stuck with what you can edit. You can not refine things, sometimes you need to re-do some parts again.

There are some other tools for specialized looks, like shapes all made of cubes, but among those limitations, the software has the ability to continue editing the same project.

To answer your question I played a bit with it. And yes, it requires a lot of creativity to know what to do with limited tools.

Paint 3D is the successor of MSPaint, and there is a great example of what can be done with limited tools.

https://youtu.be/v2g5qbvb7F4
[image]

It is quite obvious that a skilled person can do wonders, even with limited tools, or materials, even with a stick on a beach. (Or a bucket and some water)

<sub>I will try to make something later. It will be interesting:o)</sub>

Comment: Playdoh is actually pretty useful for people who do animation or if you need a quick fillet for a casting art that need to be out right now.

Comment: Yeap. If people can make awesome sculptures with sand, I'm pretty sure someone can do wonders with anything. I added that to the answer.

Comment: And this is why i use illustrator.

Comment: That's really rather magnificent. I could spend 50 hours attempting that & still end up with something that looked like a 6-year-old drew it. I'll stick to photography, thanks ;)